# Using ctypes in Python to access dll

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm attempting to access a function in an external dll using Python 2.7. The function requires a keyword argument first, however Python throws an error as if I were trying to access a Python function.

```
import ctypes
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
k = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/test/api/windows/testdll32.dll")          

def test():
    funccall = k.DLLFUNC(DLLVAR = 1, x, y, z)
test
```

The error is :SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

I get that you can't do that in Python, but the function that I am trying to access is not a Python function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you call it without the keyword in front? What do the functions look like in your dll?

Comment: Its a general error to have keyword arguments before positional arguments, as ryugie suggests try calling it like `k.DLLFUNC(1, x, y, z)` or whatever order is correct for those arguments. If am right `DLLFUNC` is your c function, which wouldn't understand keyword args anyway.